# When do we "bootstrap" and then use "t-dist" versus just using "t-dist"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, normal-distribution, bootstrap, t-distribution

I'm taking a Data Analysis class on Coursera, and we are learning about bootstrapping when you have a small sample size (>30). What I don't understand, is when do you bootstrap and then use the t-distribution, and when do you just use the t-distribution? For example, we looked at 21 apartments for rent, and bootstrapped to continue on and calculate our test statistic and confidence interval. We also did an example where we looked at the mercury levels of 13 dolphins near Japan, but we only used the t-distribution, and never performed the boot strapping simulation.

**Q:** *What are the conditions that tell you which situation to go with? I hope this makes sense. Please stick with basics, as this is all new to me and I won't understand something super advanced written in hieroglyphics.*

Comment: "Small sample size (>30)" is a contradiction in terms.  The statement of which that is a part is also, on its face, incorrect, because the theoretical (and intuitive) support for the bootstrap requires the sample size to be *large.*  Right away that produces a clear conceptual distinction: t tests were originally developed (and still applied) to *small* samples. There are many criteria for determining when a t distribution might be applicable: consider searching our site for examples.